# Create User using Python-Jira

Tags: python, jira

Looking into different methods to create users remotely. Does anyone have an example of this working, or know why this chunk of code isnt working?

```
import jira.client
from jira.client import JIRA

print('starting script')

options = {'server' : 'http://<server>.atlassian.net'}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('<username>', '<password>'))
jira.add_user('testUser1', '<emailaddress>', '12345', 'testUser1', False, True, False)

print('ending script')
```

Whenever I run this, I get a brick of error code that ends with "response text = {"errorMessages":["Either the 'username' or the 'key' query parameters need to be provided"],"errors":{}}"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why dont you user API calls with Python?

Comment: Do you know what does directoryId refers ? In this case I guess it is 12345. How did you learned DirectoryId of the project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting options, I used http instead of https. This fixed my problem